# Asp.net core hotchocolate graphql: ObjectType with an Interface in it throws error "unable to resolve"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a problem with an interface that is inside of another class.
my Class looks like

```
public class Plugin
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
      public string? Description { get; set; }
      public string? PluginType { get; set; }
      public string SystemPath { get; set; }
      public double Version { get; set; } 
      public bool Active { get; set; } 

      public IPlugin Plugin { get; set; }

      public PluginDto()
      {
          Version = 1.0d;
      }
}
```

And I want to return that type in a query it will throw, on the server startup, an exception that the schema can't resolve IPlugin.

HotChocolate.SchemaException: Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type referenceInput: IPlugin.

I tried creating an Interfacetype for IPlugin and in the Objecttype i wrote
"descriptor.Field(x => x.Plugin).Type();"
that did't work
I wrote "descriptor.Ignore(x=>x.Plugin);"
that did't work aswell.

IPlugin can be a class from another assembly that inherits from this interface.
And yes it should be an interface.

So my question is, what I can do to return an interface inside of another class?
Am I doing something wrong ?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you registered an implementation to that interface?

Comment: yeah and that was the fix, I thought it would work without an implementation

Comment: Are you able to post your fix as an answer? What exactly did you do to fix this issue?

Comment: @GoonPontoon I needed to register the type, see here https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/interfaces